# tabulator JavaScript , how to export a table to excel file with right to left orientation

Tags: tabulator

i have a table in tabulator js, the table displays properly in RTL on the web page , but when i export the table to excel as xlsx file and open the downloaded file, the worksheet loads as left to right.

i have tried to read the documentation but couldn't find a way to control the orientation on the export.

is there a way to do it?